# Smoothness class of a product

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C^k(\Bbb R)$ be the set of $k$-differentiable functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Given a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, let $k_f$ denote the maximal $k$ such that $f\in C^k(\Bbb R)$. Is there a relationship among $k_f$, $k_g$, and $k_{fg}$?

Example: Let $f(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=x$. Then $f\in C^0$ and $g\in C^\infty$ and $fg$ is given by
$$ (fg)(x) = \begin{cases}
-x^2 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
x^2 & \text{if } x \geq 0
\end{cases} $$
which is $C^1$. So, what is the relationship ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$k_{fg}\geq \{\min{k_g,k_f}\}$. That the inequality holds is clear from the product rule. That the lower bound can be achieved is clear from taking $f=1$ and $g\in C^k(\mathbb{R})$. So, we can't do better.